# Can't understand how the answer to an equation that adds a long and a float then multiplies by a double makes sense

Tags: java, double, long-integer, addition

I have an equation `j + f * d` where `j = 4 long` and `f = 5.0F float` and `d = 6.0 double` and the answer is `34.0 double`

I understand how the 34.0 is a `double`.

I don't understand how the equation ends up as 34.0, does `5.0F != 5` when using it to multiply?

```
J = 4 (long)
f = 5.0F (float)
d = 6.0 (double)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of operations takes precedence. Multiplication occurs before addition.

```
j + f * d
4 + 5.0 * 6.0
4 + 30.0
34.0
```

This link details in full the Java operator precedence. It is good information to memorize: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the order of operations that Kon mentions, `double` is really the only type that will not lose precision since 6.0 is already a `double`. Java will **not** attempt to downgrade the output type based on the values contained within them. It just uses the smallest type that is compatible with the input types. Since you already have a `double` (the "largest" primitive data type, i.e. has the largest range of numbers), Java outputs that.

So, in a sense, you're correct that `5.0f` isn't the same as `5` (ever, actually, not just in multiplication). `5` is an integer type; `5.0f` is a float type. Java will not automatically downgrade the result to a data type that cannot hold as many different numbers.

(Don't accept this answer. Kon's information is more important.)